# Fetching data into routes.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am new to laravel. I have a table which contains the navigation titles. I want to fetch all the titles from the table into routes.php

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: There is no `routes.php` in Laravel

Comment: @kerbholz i mean i routes/web.php

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer**: Yes

**Long Answer**: Yes, but it is not an appropriate way to retrieve

```
//routes.php

Route::get('testing', function(){
    $titles = \DB::table('navigation')->pluck('titles'));
    dd($titles);
});
```

The better way is to use Route -> Controller -> View way

```
//routes.php
Route::get('testing', 'NavigationController@index');

//NavigationController.php

public function index(){
    $titles = Naviation::pluck('titles'));
    dd($titles);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here check the [laravel routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing)  how it works.

```
    Route::get('get-titles', function () {
      $result = \DB::table('tableName')->get();
    });
```